# What's the problem with fgets() input in c within a switch, loop or if statement?

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, input, fgets

I tried to ask for some string input with the fgets() function, it is working as long as I don't try to construct a loop or if statement around it. I thought I need to solve this with a pointer, but the char array named "city" already acts as one. What's my fault?

```html
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <string.h>

int main(){
int anfangEnde;
char city[20];

/*This is a comment*/
do{
    printf("Tippe 1 fuer fortfahren und 2 fuer beenden:\n");
    scanf("%d", &anfangEnde);
    switch(anfangEnde){
    case 1:
        printf("gebe Stadtnamen ein: \n");
        fgets(city, 20, stdin);
        //Input geht nicht in if Statements. KP wieso.
        printf("%sund es hat hingehauen.\n", city);
        break; 
    case 2:
        printf("Programm beendet\n");
        break; 
    default: 
        printf("Fehlerhafte Eingabe\n");
    }
}while((anfangEnde != 1) && (anfangEnde != 2));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a 'hanging' newline character in the input buffer after your `scanf` call, which is fed to the `fgets` call. Quick fix: add `getchar();` after the `scanf` line. Longer answer: Looking for a suitable duplicate ...

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much.

Comment: You can 'accept' the proposed duplicate in the blue banner/box you should see.